# absolute positioned element moves along with its neighbour

Tags: javascript, react-native

Well I've got an element which moves up as the keyboard arrives to avoid hiding bottom content which is important. This element uses a `bottom` to move it up. I have hamburger icon with position: absolute and its offsets, it was inside the moving element before, but I moved it out and wrapped both elements with jsx fragment like this

```
return (
  <>
    <MovingComponent .../>
    <HamburgerComponent .../>
  </>
)
```

I had this Hamburger both before and after the MovingComponent, didn't work.

Hamburger styles:

```js
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 50,
    top: 60,
    left: 40,
    padding: 10,
```

Moving component styles(wp, hp are react-native-responsive-screen funcs):

```js
    position: 'absolute',
    height: hp(100),
    width: wp(100),
    // custom bottom(0 default)
```

I'm surprised the element is actually outside the moving element but still moves accordingly to him, how can I fix it?

Actual behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O30Kb.jpg

Expected behaviour: hamburger doesn't actually move up

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the current result and indications of desired result? thanks

Comment: how do you achieve the effect of making things going up? With a component like `KeyboardAvoidingView` or with android related options into manifest file?

Comment: @vitosorriso alike to KeyboardAvoidingView, this one didn't fit what I needed so I made up my own one, it uses bottom to move it up